# Should I use useRef or lift state up to deal with the following case?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In some cases, I have to send a request in the parent component while the param is the children component's state.
Can I do like this?

```
function Parent() {
    const paramRef = useRef(null)
    return <Modal onConfirm={()=>{request(paramRef.current)}}>
               <Child bindParam = {(param) => paramRef.current = param} />
           </Modal>
}

function Child({bindParam}) {
    const [state, setState] = useState('foo')
    useEffect(()=>{
        bindParam(state)
    }, [state, bindParam])
    
    return ...
}
```

or I do have to lift Child's state up.
Sorry for my poor English. Do I make the question clear?

Comment: I think you need to move state to Parent component) it's bad idea to pass instance of component somewhere else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please move your state "useState()" to your parent component and pass it down to child component as props.

```
function Parent() {
     const [state, setState] = useState('foo')
    return <Modal onConfirm={()=>{request(paramRef.current)}}>
               <Child state={state}  setState={setState}/>
           </Modal>
}

function Child({state, setState}) {
   
    useEffect(()=>{ 
     setState('foo1');
    }, [])
    
    return ...
}
```

Now, you should be able to change the state either at parent or at child, but you need to be aware that state change will re-render the component.